# How to convert Google Earth polygons CSV to KML

Tags: polygon, coordinates, google-earth, utm

I have converted polygon coordinates from Google Earth (KMZ to CSV) in UTM and now I need to convert that back from CSV to KML. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Which software did you use?

Comment: well we would need to see your csv, or at least a couple lines of it, but yeah, kml is just XML so conversion is easy